# Tax write off for week spent at my own VRBO rental?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property, vrbo

I own two different VRBO rentals in two different states. I would like to stay in each at least 1 week per year for no other reason than to inspect them, fix minor things if needed and in general ensure it's still a comfortable / pleasing place for my renters.

I am fully aware that I can write off repairs and travel to these rentals as well as the cleaning bill after I've left. Can I somehow write off the lost rent since I'm blocking it off for myself for the week at a time that it would otherwise rent-out?

One of these rentals is fairly seasonal. The other is pretty much booked all the time except on the rare occasion.

Comment: I would say that you would need to keep good records of the work you did there and the time required to do that work. Carrying out work is different from taking a holiday. Regarding writing off loss rent, I don't know what the issue here is anyway - if it is not rented out for a week you will not receive any rent for that week, so you just wouldn't be claiming income for that week and not writing anything off. If you do any work - keep receipts and you can claim those as deductions against your rent/income from the rest of the year.

Comment: Do you accrue 52 weeks of rental income whether or not you receive that in cash?

Comment: @user662852
No, there will be at least 2 - 3 weeks a year that it's not rented at all for a good 7 days straight. The issue however, is that I don't know ahead of time what weeks those will be. In order to reserve flights to the rental, I would have to block out a week at least 3 weeks in advance. Thus, in the end I don't know if that week would have rented out or not because I already have flights and it would be blocked off for me.

Comment: I believe that you can only write off money you actually spend. You are already paying less tax than if you rented the VRBO out for that week, because you don't have income for that week to pay tax on.

Comment: @DJClayworth
I guess it would be more or less a wash if I actually paid myself? ie. reserved the rental / charged it to my visa card and then wrote that off as an expense? Because, I would be also claiming the income, so net zero and a lot of work.